# Getting blank response and ref# error with batch update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to update a Pivot table on a Google Sheet using GScript. I have created the following request:

```
{
  "updateCells": {
    "rows": {
      "values": [
        {
          "pivotTable": {
            "source": {
              "sheetId": 698433721,
              "startRowIndex": 6,
              "startColumnIndex": 0,
              "endRowIndex": 193,
              "endColumnIndex": 5
            },
            "rows": {
              "sourceColumnOffset": 3,
              "showTotals": true,
              "sortOrder": "DESCENDING",
              "valueBucket": {
                "buckets": [
                  {
                    "stringValue": "9/4/2019"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "columns": {
              "sourceColumnOffset": 2,
              "sortOrder": "ASCENDING"
            },
            "values": [
              {
                "summarizeFunction": "SUM",
                "sourceColumnOffset": 4
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }, 
    "start": {
      "sheetId": 111150237
    }, 
    "fields": "pivotTable"
  }
}
```

When I send it through batchUpdate all I get is a blank response. When I look at the sheet that was updated all I get is a "REF#" eror in the first cell. I have no idea how to debug this.
Here is the new shot at the JSON:

```
{
  "requests":[
    {
      "updateCells":{
        "rows":[
          {
            "values":[
               {
                "pivotTable":{
                  "source":{
                    "sheetId":698433721,
                    "startRowIndex":6,
                    "startColumnIndex":0,
                    "endRowIndex":193,
                    "endColumnIndex":5
                  },
                  "rows":[
                    {
                      "sourceColumnOffset":3,
                      "showTotals":true,
                      "sortOrder":"DESCENDING",
                      "valueBucket":{
                        "buckets":[
                          {
                            "stringValue":"9/4/2019"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "columns":[
                    {
                      "sourceColumnOffset":2,
                      "sortOrder":"ASCENDING"
                    }
                  ],
                  "values":[
                    {
                      "summarizeFunction":"SUM",
                      "sourceColumnOffset":4
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "start":{
          "sheetId":111150237
        },
        "fields":"pivotTable"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The response i get is as follows:
response:{"replies":[{}],"spreadsheetId":"12O5x-I_ABP-qw_NBevQ2T4GnKk9bw49ThdRPPG5_0ic"}

Comment: Are you getting a valid response (even if blank)? As far as I can see, some fields in the request body are not correctly written. According to the official documentation, the field `rows` in `UpdateCellsRequest` should have an array of `RowData` objects as value, not directly a `RowData` object, and the fields `rows` and `columns` in `PivotTable` should have an array of `PivotGroup` objects instead of a `PivotGroup` object. Not sure if there is another problem involved though, without having more information on the subject.

Comment: For further reference: [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateCellsRequest), [PivotTable](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/pivot-tables#PivotTable)

Comment: I am attempting to follow the pattern in this post from Google.
https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/pivot

Comment: Could you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (of course free of any sensitive information), together with the outcome you expect?

Comment: I wish I could but that is not possible.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate#response-body), the replies to some updates may be empty. This is the case in the example shown in the link you provided. The issue is the `REF#` error you are getting. It would be really useful to look at a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, *free of sensitive information*, to understand what's going on.